# mysql not starting on wsl Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

During the installation of phpmyadmin, I ran into this problem that MySQL doesn't start. I executed commands as shown below.

```bash
// Apache
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 restart

// MariaDB
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client mariadb-backup
 
sudo apt install mysql-server

// restart
sudo service mysql restart // not starting
```

When I execute sudo service mysql start, the message Starting MySQL database server mysqld appears but doesn't finish the process for a while and eventually fail.

```
/var/log/error.log
/var/log/mysql/mysql.err     
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

are empty.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: you need to put error log here.

Comment: but
/var/log/error.log
/var/log/mysql/mysql.err     
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log  
/var/log/syslog
dont exist. (I thought they existed at the time when i post the question but found out they didnt.